# How to determine how many columns has a table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

How to determine how many columns has a table in T-SQL.
Can I do a query to the database dictionary to get this information like in Oracle databases?
I´m using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```